# Dictionary won't populate using "for" loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that takes in lines of data about switches. So far, I've split the data into so that each line contains an ip, max, and total. These all populate fine in the dictionary, but I'm noticing that each time I iterate over the dictionary structure below, I override the dictionary. I would like to append multiple entries to one dictionary.

```
for line in lines:
    switch_ip = buildings[build_pre]
    total = int(line.split(';')[3])
    MAX = int(line.split(';')[4])
    if switch_ip not in data:
        data = { buildings[build_pre]:
                   { switch_ip:
                       { 'max': MAX,
                         'total':total
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Currently the output for `data` is:

```
{'Azalea': {'Azalea': {'max': 14, 'total': 56}}}
```

I would like however, the output to look more like:

```
{'Azalea': {'Azalea': {'max': 14, 'total': 56}},
 'Traditions': {'Traditions': {'max': 13, 'total': 20}}}
```

Comment: What dictionary are you trying to populate? What are the values of all those (global) variables being referenced, e.g. `lines`. `buildings`, and `build_pre`?

Comment: I don't understand how `buildings[build_pre]` can return different values on each iteration if you dont change `build_pre` in the loop. This question needs an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You're redefining the dictionary inside each loop. Instead, you want to define the dictionary once, and then append to the dictionary inside each loop.

```
data = {}

for line in lines:
  switch_ip = buildings[build_pre]
  total = int(line.split(';')[3])
  MAX = int(line.split(';')[4])
  if switch_ip not in data:
    data[buildings[build_pre]] = {
      switch_ip: {
        'max': MAX,
        'total':total
      }
    }
```

This way you're adding a key to the dictionary on each iteration rather than trying to build a whole new dictionary.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Is there any way i'd be able to do the same thing for the switch IP? variable?                                                                                        {'Azalea': {'10.16.62.40': {'max': 12, 'total': 57}},
 'Wildwood B': {'10.17.38.32': {'max': 10, 'total': 33}}}                                                                                                              Is what I'm getting, but i'd like it to return the building for every ip(there are about a hundred) so it looks like the switch_ip dictionary is being reset with each iteration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cat be rewrite as follows:

```
for line in lines:
    switch_ip = buildings[build_pre]
    t = line.split(';')
    total, max_ = int(t[3]), int(t[4])
    data.setdefault(switch_ip, {
        switch_ip: {'max': max_, 'total': total}
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

Python by default refers to variables as local. It is could be adding to a local `data` dictionary, so you could try defining `global data` in one of the lines before the for loop.

However, it depends on how and where you are using it.